# Read specific XML data in C#

Tags: c#, xml

Right now, I want to obtain some specific information inside an XML file. Here is what I have for the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<root>
  <world>
    <region name="TestRegion">
      <area name="TestArea">
        <building name="Outside">
          <room name="TutorialRoom">
            <stuffToTake>All the text I want to take</stuffToTake>
          </room>
        </building>
      </area>
    </region>
  </world>
</root>
```

I looked online on how to do this with code, and I saw this implementation. I just then adapted it to my code:

```
XElement xelement = XElement.Load("..\\..\\LocationDatabase.xml");

var TextToDisplay = from regions in xelement.Elements("world")
                   where (string)regions.Element("region").Attribute("name") == "TestRegion"
                   where (string)regions.Element("region").Element("area").Attribute("name") == "TestArea"
                   where (string)regions.Element("region").Element("area").Element("building").Attribute("name") == "Outside"
                   where (string)regions.Element("region").Element("area").Element("building").Element("room").Attribute("name") == "TutorialRoom"
                   select regions;

foreach (var xEle in TextToDisplay)
{
    Console.WriteLine(xEle.Element("region").Element("area").Element("building").Element("room").Element("stuffToTake").Value);
}
```

And so far, this works fine. 
[image: Working Console window]
The issue here is when I add some data ABOVE the XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<root>
  <world>
   <region name="LolNope">
      <area name="TestArea">
        <building name="Outside">
          <room name="TutorialRoom">
            <stuffToTake>All the text I want to take</stuffToTake>
          </room>
        </building>
      </area>
    </region>
    <region name="TestRegion">
      <area name="TestArea">
        <building name="Outside">
          <room name="TutorialRoom">
            <stuffToTake>All the text I want to take</stuffToTake>
          </room>
        </building>
      </area>
    </region>
  </world>
</root>
```

Then, it just turns an empty Console Window:
[image: Blank, empty Console Window]

What exactly is the issue here? I am assuming that it checks if the first region has the name TestRegion, but since it doesn't it fails and stops checking the rest.

Comment: Where I learnt to use it: http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=564. NOTE: I have never used LINQ before, but it seems alot of people on StackExchange said to use LINQ for some reason.

Comment: There's a difference between `.Element` and `.Elements`. One returns the *first* element with that name, the other returns *all* elements.

Comment: Ahh, I see. So should I change all instances of element to elements?

Comment: Doing that didn't help :(. It just said I can't check for an attribute() or .Name, @J.Steen

Comment: inside <world> you have two regions now. You need to adapt the LINQ expression. (Try to understand what your monstrous LINQ expression does, break it down to simpler expressions, work with individual XElements)

Comment: Yeah. You will need to modify the rest of your query as well. If you find linq to be an insurmountable challenge in this case, why use it in the first place? Use a technique that you're comfortable with instead.

Comment: I would like to, but it seems that the majorty of questions on Stack Exchange on how to do it say to use LINQ to XML. I looked abit on XMLReader, but I could not find how to specify data to take given specific attributes in nodes. Is it possible for you to post a possible answer, and I learn how you did it by dissembling what you did @J.Steen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is chain your queries in linq-to-xml, selecting each group of elements at a time.

```
// all worlds
var worlds = xelement.Elements("world");

// all regions in the worlds where the attribute "name" is "TestRegion"
var regions = worlds.Elements("region")
                    .Where (region => (string)region.Attribute("name") == "TestRegion");

// all areas in the specified regions where the attribute "name" is "TestArea"
var areas = regions.Elements("area")
                   .Where (area => (string)area.Attribute("name") == "TestArea");

// all buildings in the specified areas where the attribute "name" is "Outside"
var buildings = areas.Elements("building")
                     .Where (building => (string)building.Attribute("name") == "Outside");

// all rooms in the specified buildings where the attribute "name" is "TutorialRoom"
var rooms = buildings.Elements("room")
                     .Where (room => (string)room.Attribute("name") == "TutorialRoom");

// all stuff to take in the specified rooms
var stuffs = rooms.Elements("stuffToTake");

// all the contents of the stuffs as an enumerable (there might be more than one, after all)
var values = stuffs.Select (stuff => stuff.Value);

foreach (var value in values)
{
    Console.WriteLine(value);
}
```

And, without intermediate variables:

```
var values = xelement.Elements("world")
    .Elements("region").Where (region => (string)region.Attribute("name") == "TestRegion")
    .Elements("area").Where (area => (string)area.Attribute("name") == "TestArea")
    .Elements("building").Where (building => (string)building.Attribute("name") == "Outside")
    .Elements("room").Where (room => (string)room.Attribute("name") == "TutorialRoom")
    .Elements("stuffToTake")
    .Select(stuff => stuff.Value);
```

Comment: Ahh, I see. So you specifically break it up to multiple bits in the first, simple checking for each one as you go down?

Comment: If I ever have issue with a moderately complex linq-query, yeah. Do each part in turn, narrowing down your query until you have what you want. That way you can debug, recheck, rewrite, refine, as you go along.

Comment: Is it OK practice to do so much LINQ to get a specific text? Should I have restructured the XML to suit my needs, or is this amount of LINQ fine?

Comment: You're absolutely fine like this, for now.

Comment: Ok, thanks so much @J.Steen, it works brilliantly now :D. I just have one more thing if you can answer. There will only be one instance were all the requirements will be met. Is there a way to make it that once it found that one instance, that it will stop looking and continue with the rest of the code (similarly to the 'break' command in C#). If you think I should ask this in a different question instead of asking in a comment, that I'll do that then ;)

Comment: You should probably ask that in a different question. And try first on your own, with this code, to see what you can do. You might stumble on your own answer as you write your new question.

Comment: Ok, then, i'll do that

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this, if you want to drill down, to the stuffToTake:

```
var result = root.Elements("world")
                 .Elements("region")
                 .Where (r => r.Attribute("name").Value == "TestRegion")
                 .Elements("area")
                 .Elements("building")
                 .Elements("room")
                 .Elements("stuffToTake")
                 .Select (r => r.Value);

result.Dump();
```

If you want to filter at a deeper level for area or buildung or a room, just apply a where clause after you have selected the Element and then filter by the Attribute:

```
                  .Elements("region")
                 .Where (r => r.Attribute("name").Value == "TestRegion")
                 .Elements("area")
                 .Where(ar => ar.Attribute("name").Value == "TestArea")
                 .Elements("building")
                 .Where(bui => bui.Attribute("name").Value == "Outside")
                 .Elements("room")
```

I tend to put all methods below the previous, but you can also put the `Where()` method directly behind the Element -selection if this fits better to your reading and understanding:

```
.Elements("region").Where (r => r.Attribute("name").Value == "TestRegion")
.Elements("area").Where(ar => ar.Attribute("name").Value == "TestArea")
.Elements("building").Where(bui => bui.Attribute("name").Value == "Outside")
.Elements("room")...
```

The important part is to filter by the Attribute name. Try it for yourself:
http://share.linqpad.net/vns5le.linq

Comment: When I look at your code, it seems you only check for the value in Region. What happens if I need something specific for area, building and room?